# Divi theme Blog Month Traslation from english to german

Tags: wordpress, plugins, divi

I am trying to create a plugin which translates wordpress blog month name from english to german i am using divi theme so far i have added

```
<?php
```

/*
Plugin Name: German Months
Description: Translate Blog Month Names to German
Version: 1.0
*/

error_reporting(E_ALL);

function german_month_plugin_menu() {
add_menu_page(
'German Month Plugin Settings',
'German Month',
'manage_options',
'german-month-plugin',
'german_month_plugin_page',
);
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'german_month_plugin_menu');

function translate_month_to_german($date) {

```
$german_months = array(
    'Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'
);

$date = strftime('%B', strtotime($date));
$date = str_replace($date, $german_months[intval(date('n', strtotime($date))) - 1], $date);

return $date;
```

}

add_filter('the_date', 'translate_month_to_german');
add_filter('get_the_date', 'translate_month_to_german');

?>

above code is working on wordpress default theme but not working on divi can someone help me why this hapening ?